# PyCharm debug window no longer showing below the code

Tags: pycharm

I've used PyCharm Community for almost two years (currently version 2023.2.1).  I have always used it with the Project window showing in the left sidebar, the code windows (one tab for each window) showing in the center of the screen and the debug and debug console windows showing at the bottom.  When I enter debug mode (shift-F9) the debug and debug consoles show at the bottom, below the code.  When I exit debug mode (ctrl-F2) my original layout is restored, minus the debug and console windows.  That was the default when i first installed it.

Today I apparently hit some magic keystroke combo and now the debug window occupies the entire screen when I enter debug mode, and I can't see any of my breakpoints in the code as it runs -- I just see the debug window.

I've researched and looked through myriad options, but I don't know how to get my layout back.

I really appreciated any help on this.

Thanks.

Update:  I can get my original layout partially back with Window - Layouts - Restore Current Layout.  But I no longer see the Debug and Console windows at the bottom of the screen -- instead it shows Frames, Variables and Console.  I can't see the console at all when I click the Console tab.  How can I restore to the default Debug and Console panes ONLY showing below the code while I'm in debug mode?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem.  To clarify my question above, I want the debug & console windows at the bottom of the screen, below the code and the Project Explorer sidebar, with two tabs:  Debug and Console.  Instead, they were stacked with a new tab, "Threads and Variables" and "Console."

To get it back to the way it was, I right-clicked on the "Threads and Variables" tab at the bottom of the screen and chose "Layout" then "Restore Default Layout."  Now I have what I want back again.  The "Debug" tab now says "Threads and Variables" but it shows the same information as before, but with variables too.